# DataTable.ajax.reload doesnt seem to reload the table with new data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

Banging my head against a brick wall here. I have a Datatable that is populated by GET call to an api from a dropdown box. Ideally i want the user to select an option in the dropdown and the table will reload with the data from the call.
The api is getting called and data is being returned with each selection but the table doesnt display the data or get refreshed like i would expect.

CheckIn.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CheckIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CheckIn</h2>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("Customers", 
    new SelectList(Model, "Id", "Name"), "Please select a customer", 
    new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customers"})
</div>

<table id="rentals" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var customerId;
            var table = $("#rentals").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/RentalsApi/',
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.id = customerId ? customerId : -1;
                    },
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "name"
                    }
                ]
            });

            $('#customers').on('change', function (e) {
                console.log(this.value);
                customerId = this.value;
                table.ajax.reload();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

API

```
// GET /api/RentalsApi/{1}
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetRental(int id)
{
    if (id == -1) return Json(new System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult());

    var customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    return Ok(customer);
}
```

Customer Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter customer's name.")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }

        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Membership Type")]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [Min18YearsIfAMember]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your ajax api call as normal and then use this to redraw the table

```
table=$("#rentals").DataTable()
table.clear().rows.add(newData).draw(); //newData is the data you get from your ajax call
```